# Spring Response to Java Object when Json KEY keeps changing

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, rest, jackson

I am calling an external rest-API from my spring boot code which returns JSON something like this.

```
 {
    "Jack": {
        "employeeId": 1,
        "active": 1,
        "hours": 40
 },
     "Ryan": {
        "employeeId": 2,
        "active": 1,
        "hours": 40
  },
     "Ken": {
        "employeeId": 3,
        "active": 1,
        "hours": 40
   }
}
```

I am trying to convert this to java pojo using jackson and using RestTemplate to call this 
I am not sure how to create java class for something like this, as the employee name keeps changing and there is No "Name key" in JSON. I can create a class for the fields employeeid,active and hours but now sure how to accommodate the employee name

Is there a way to convert these to java objects

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to change the API response like `"name":"Jack"`.It seems that it is not a good json form, isn't it?

But if you can do this,maybe this question will not exists.

The other way to convert is to convert is as `Map<String,Object>` and then you can get key set and you can handle the object as usual json.